# Type of energy in energy band diagram of a solid

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

What type of energy do the energy levels in the energy band diagram of a solid such as silicon (Si) represent? Potential energy? Kinetic energy? Or total energy?

I saw in a book that kinetic energy of an electron in conduction band is $E-E_c$, which $E_c$ is the lowest level of conduction band.
Does this mean that $E_c$ is potential energy and any other energy level higher than this level but in conduction band is total energy (that is: $E_c + E_{\mathrm{kinetic}}$)?

[image]

Comment: What is the "bar graph" of a solid?

Comment: Energy band diagram

Comment: Also [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/754963/42377) is strictly related. None of them has still been answered.