# Why does the bottom of the conduction band correspond to the potential energy of an electron?

Tags: potential, potential-energy, semiconductor-physics, chemical-potential, fermi-energy

While proving that Fermi level is constant throughout any system in thermal equilibrium, all the books I saw the proof in (for example, [Sze](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471143235) and [Shur](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136664962)) assume the following:

> the bottom of the conduction band $E_C$ corresponds to the potential energy of an
> electron

Then they derive the electric field as:

$$-q E = -(\text{gradient of electron potential energy}) = -\frac{dE_C}{dx}$$

Then they plug $E$ into the drift current formula.

1. **But it is the Fermi level $E_F$ that represents potential energy. $E_C$ merely represents the  minimal energy electron needs to move to the conduction band.**
2. **Regardless of how to correctly express potential energy, the electric field must come from the gradient of *electric* potential energy specifically, not from the entire potential energy, that includes chemical potential energy as well.**